# Linked List Retain Function Not Working

Tags: c++, linked-list

This was an old assignment on a data structure course. The objective is to complete the retain function which works like such: listy.retain(listx) and the result is to REMOVE elements in listy that are NOT contained in listx.

I have tried writing my own code as below.

```
template<class Type>
void linkedList<Type>::retain(const linkedList<Type>& other) 
{
    // Implement this function
    node<Type>* y = first;
    node<Type>* x;

    while(y != NULL)
    {
        x = other.first;

        while(x != NULL)
        {
            if(x->info == y->info)
                break;
        }
        if(x == NULL)
            remove(x->info);
        y = y->link;
    }
}
```

Also, the remove function used is provided in a part of the assignment.

```
template<class Type>
void linkedList<Type>::remove(const Type& x) 
{   //remove the first instance of x in the list

    node<Type> *p, *q;
    p = first;
    q = NULL;

    while (p != NULL && p->info != x)
    {
        q = p;
        p = p->link;
    }

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p == first)         
            first = first->link;         
        else         
            q->link = p->link;

        if (p == last)
            last = q;

        delete p;
        count--;        
    }
}
```

It builds without errors but originally it was supposed to display the new listy but all now it stops outputting altogether after the initial conditions.

```
**** Part-1 unordered linkedList ****

-- Test 1A --
listx (len = 7) : 5 3 7 7 5 4 3 
listy (len = 7) : 2 8 4 7 3 1 9
```

Any ideas?? This is my first time posting so any feedback is welcome, and thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not iterating `x` in the inner `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `retain` has an infinite loop.

```
    x = other.first;

    while(x != NULL)
    {
        if(x->info == y->info)
            break;
    }
```

If the first `x->info != y->info` when the loop repeats the same iteration for ths same node `x` because `x` is not being changed.

And this statement

```
    if(x == NULL)
        remove(x->info);
```

should be substituted to

```
    if(x == NULL)
        remove(y->info);
```

But in any case it is better to remove nodes in place that is within function retain than to make a separate call to function remove.

And this statement

```
    y = y->link;
```

can result in undefined behaviour if the node y will be deleted by the preceding call of function remove.

At least the inner loop should look like

```
x = other.first;

while( x != NULL && x->info != y->info ) x = x->link;

if ( x == NULL )
{
    node<Type>* tmp = y->link;
    remove( y->info );
    y = tmp;
}
else
{
    y = y->link;
}
```

Also you should check whether the deliting node is the node `first`. Otherwise node `first` can be invalid.

Comment: would'nt `remove(x->info)` be equivalent to `remove(y->info)`?

Comment: @gaurav sehgal  x->info is the value that must be present in the list.

Comment: isn't `y->info` equal to `x->info`. calling `remove(y->info)` will remove a node with value `y->info` from list `y`.So calling `remove(x->info)` will do the same as long as `y->info=x->info`.

Comment: @gaurav sehgal  According to the assignment you have to delete nodes that are not in the second list. If x->info is equal to y->info then this means that you are deleting a valid node.

Comment: My appologies. Completely misunderstood.I should have read the post carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this 
if(x == NULL)
      remove(x->info);
Should be 
if(x != NULL)
      remove(x->info);